# Symmetric Tree Check in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, tree

Inspired by [This LeetCode Question](https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/94/trees/627).

Instead of checking if every layer is symmetric, it instead checks if any *aren't*. This allows the program to leave early is an early layer fails the test. I'm looking for performance mostly, as I loop through each element in the list, instead of each layer. All feedback is appreciated and considered.

```
"""
This program determines if a given binary
tree is a mirror of itself

Example:

For example, this binary tree [1,2,2,3,4,4,3] is symmetric:

    1
   / \
  2   2
 / \ / \
3  4 4  3

But the following [1,2,2,null,3,null,3] is not:

    1
   / \
  2   2
   \   \
   3    3
"""

def is_symmetric(tree: list) -> bool:
    """
    Returns if the passed tree is symmetric

    :param tree: A list representing a binary tree
    """

    interval = 2
    start = 0
    end = 1
    for _ in range(len(tree)):
        # Find next layer
        layer = tree[start:end]

        # Determine if layer isn't mirror
        if layer != list(reversed(layer)):
            return False

        # Setup for next layer
        start = end
        end = (2 ** interval) - 1
        interval += 1

    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':

    assert is_symmetric([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3]) # True
    assert not is_symmetric([1, 2, 2, None, 3, None, 3]) # False
```

Comment: Clearly, `[1, 2, 2, None, 4, 4, None]` is symmetric.  If `None` represents a missing node, would `[1, 2, 2, None, 4, 4]` be considered symmetric?  As in, incomplete layers could be considered padded with `None`'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. The function may fail for a tree with an incomplete last layer.  For example:

   ```
   is_symmetric([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3])  returns True, but it should be False.
   ```

This can be fixed by checking if layers have the expected length.

```
if len(layer) != (end - start) or layer != list(reversed(layer)):
        return False
```

2. The for loop iterates more times than needed.  The loop only needs to run for each layer in the tree, not for each node.  A tree with n layers has 2**n - 1 nodes. It may not matter for small trees, but a tree with 20 layers has over a million nodes.  Replace the for loop with a while loop:

   ```
   while start < len(tree):
   ...
   ```
3. Okay, three things.  `interval` isn't needed.  Use:

   ```
   end = 2 * end + 1
   ```

The revised routine:

```
def is_symmetric(tree: list) -> bool:
    """
    Returns if the passed tree is symmetric

    :param tree: A list representing a binary tree
    """

    start = 0
    end = 1

    while start < len(tree):
        # Find next layer
        layer = tree[start:end]

        # Determine if layer isn't mirror
        if len(layer) != (end - start) or layer != list(reversed(layer)):
            return False

        # Setup for next layer
        start = end
        end = 2 * end  + 1

    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tests = [
        ([1], True),
        ([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3], True),
        ([1, 2, 2, None, 3, None, 3], False),
        ([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3], False)
        ]

    for n, (test, answer) in enumerate(tests):
        result = is_symmetric(test)
        print(f"Test {n} {'Pass' if answer==result else 'FAIL'}: is_symetric({test})")
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty good! Only two points:

Remove your parens from this -

```
end = (2 ** interval) - 1
```

due to order of operations. Also, your function is a good candidate for doc tests. Read up here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/doctest.html This will allow you to move your `assert`s into the docstring of the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @RootToo:

1. You are looping more times than needed.  You loop `n` times for a list of length `n`, where you only need to be looping [`n.bit_length()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) times.
2. The function may fail for a tree with an incomplete last layer.

The additional point I'd like to cover is you are also comparing too much.

With your binary tree `[1,2,2,3,4,4,3]`, you check that:

```
[1] == list(reversed([1]))
[2,2] == list(reversed([2,2]))
[3,4,4,3] == list(reversed([3,4,4,3]))
```

You only need to check:

```
[2] == list(reversed([2]))
[3,4] == list(reversed([4,3]))
```

This results in double the number of elements to compare, plus allocation of double the length of slices, which means copying double the number of elements that actually needed to be copied.  Plus we don't need to test the first layer, because a list of length 1 is always equal to its reverse, which is the only case of an odd number of items that complicates splitting the layers in half.

Moreover, `list(reversed(layer))` is inefficient, as a reverse iterator needs to be created, and then the `list()` needs to traverse this newly created reverse iterator to realize the required list.  `layer[::-1]` does the same thing, but without needing to create the intermediate reverse iterator.

Revised code:

```
def is_symmetric(tree: list) -> bool:
    """
    Returns if the passed tree is symmetric

    :param tree: A list representing a binary tree
    """

    n = len(tree)
    layers = n.bit_length()

    if n != 2 ** layers - 1:
        return False

    start = 1
    length = 1

    for _ in range(1, layers):
        mid = start + length
        end = mid + length
        if tree[start:mid] != tree[end-1:mid-1:-1]:
            return False

        start = end
        length *= 2

    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Test harness copied from RootToo's answer:

    tests = [
        ([], True),                          # Check empty list as special case, too!
        ([1], True),
        ([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3], True),
        ([1, 2, 2, None, 3, None, 3], False),
        ([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3], False)
        ]

    for n, (test, answer) in enumerate(tests):
        result = is_symmetric(test)
        print(f"Test {n} {'Pass' if answer==result else 'FAIL'}: is_symetric({test})")
```